# Different Behavior between a direct link and href tag in a site made in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem in a site made with bootstrap

If I set an href tag from an external page that landing on a section of my page, I have a strange behavior : the link sends me to the correct section but the navbar at the top of the menu marks the next item.
If the same link is typed directly from browser, instead, everything is working fine (the positioning of the page and the navbar menu).

Comment: Can you show us some code? Are you sure the links don't include anchors or get variables?

Comment: This question won't be answerable unless you give us more information.